# Time range query on c++ data strucutre

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

The problem: I've got a set of objects with a timestamp associated. Each time the object is refreshed the timestamp is refresh too. I need a quick way to get the objects not refresh in a time range using current time as reference. I tried to use a set, but the key in a set cannot be changed. Any idea? What is the best data structure in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). When you refresh an item `erase` it and add it with new time.

Now you can use `lower_bound` / `upper_bound` to fetch the range required.

Comment: Using the time as key?

Comment: Then I should use a multimap because the same time could be used by several objects

Comment: Yes. With multimap, you need to be sure which item do you really want to delete.

Comment: Or you could have a map of vectors of objects. When you refresh a map key, you refresh all the objects in its associated vector